# Move a document from one library to another library using event receiver

Tags: document-library, event-handlers

Suppose one document is uploaded to the Shared Document library, I need to move the document to an other library say List. There I have to create a folder with the document name and needs to place the document inside that folder. How to do this using event receiver?Please help.

Comment: I got it in the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565200/how-to-copy-newly-added-document-with-metadata-to-another-document-library

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you instead look at the Document Routing features in SharePoint 2010 instead of building custom code. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608093.aspx
I think the Document Routing can take care of all your requirements, without a single line of code :-)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion Wictor and it's a great OOB functionality that SharePoint is offering. In my case though i need to do a little more than just move the documents.
I also need to give item level permissions to user groups in the subsites. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Wictor's solution you could also envision another no-code solution by using a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow with activity "Copy List Item".

C:\Marius